# The Silverlight 3 Toolkit styles prevent the displaying of SL 3.0 data validation errors

Tags: silverlight, validation

If I apply a style from the SL 3.0 Toolkit to my application the built in SL 3.0 data validation errors are not displayed on the application edit forms. If I removed the code that applies the toolkit style to the application the SL 3.0 data validation errors appear as per normal SL 3.0 behaviour?

Has anyone else come across this problem?????

Any help is always appreciated.

Cheers
Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of research I managed to find the solution to the problem. 
A big shout out to Jesse Liberty for this [post](http://jesseliberty.com/2009/07/18/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-silverlight-3-validation/)

Basically the toolkit style control templates do not contain the necessary visual state groups for the SL 3.0 validation to work.

To fix this I copied the required visual state groups and required template markup from the standard control templates to the toolkit control templates.

ie below are the visual state group for the checkbox control.

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
    <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Below is the style for the ValidationErrorElement for a checkbox.

```
<Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" Margin="1" Visibility="Collapsed" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" ToolTipService.PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <ToolTip.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ToolTip.Triggers>
        </ToolTip>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    <Grid Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="10" Background="Transparent">
        <Path Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="0,3,0,0" Data="M 1,0 L5,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 7,2 L7,6 z"/>
        <Path Fill="#ffffff" Margin="0,3,0,0" Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 7,5 L7,7"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

You also need to place the control template for Validation tool tip in either a control or application reasource. ie

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationToolTipTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="Root" Margin="5,0" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OpenStates">
                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="Open">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="xform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualTransition>
                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Open">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="xform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="xform" X="-25"/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Border Margin="4,4,-4,-4" Background="#052A2E31" CornerRadius="5"/>
            <Border Margin="3,3,-3,-3" Background="#152A2E31" CornerRadius="4"/>
            <Border Margin="2,2,-2,-2" Background="#252A2E31" CornerRadius="3"/>
            <Border Margin="1,1,-1,-1" Background="#352A2E31" CornerRadius="2"/>
            <Border Background="#FFDC000C" CornerRadius="2"/>
            <Border CornerRadius="2">
                <TextBlock Margin="8,4,8,4" MaxWidth="250" UseLayoutRounding="false" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

I hope this helps someone out there.

Cheers
Adam

Comment: Hi, im currently having the exact same problem with my validation, can u provide a working demo of this stuff, or a link to a working demo, i followed ur links, but i lack the bandwidth to watch the videos :/