# Silverlight Toolkit DatePicker error indicator

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, datepicker, silverlight-toolkit

I don't seem to be able to get the red border line error provider for my date picker controls. I'm throwing validation exceptions on the setter of the bound to property as I have with my other controls on the form. I get the error indicator on all my controls on the form but the date picker ones. any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard one, the Visual States are missing (or were purposely excluded) in controls that were migrated from the Silverlight toolkit

Here's another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263927/the-silverlight-3-toolkit-styles-prevent-the-displaying-of-sl-3-0-data-validation) on the topic that helped me out